# Should I use dynamic SQL or is there another way

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have something like this:

```
AND t2.AUD_ORGID IN (SELECT Org_ID 
                     FROM [development_company_database].[dbo].fx_Rights_ORGIDs(@ORG_ID))
```

I am working on database A and `fx_Rights_ORGIDs` is on database B. Should I use dynamic SQL to connect to it (I don't really want to)

Dymamic:

```
SET @MANDB = (SELECT DatabseDB FROM SERVER)
SET @MANOwner = (SELECT DatabaseOwner FROM SERVER)
SET @serverMan = (Select @DatabseDB +'.'+ @DatabaseOwner ) ...

...AND t2.AUD_ORGID IN (SELECT Org_ID FROM ['+ @COMPANYDB +'].['+ @COMPANYOwner +'].fx_Rights_ORGIDs( '+ CAST(@ORG_ID AS VARCHAR) + '))

...EXEC sp_executesql @Tsql2
```

Just wondering is there a way around, I don't want to hardcode the database like this:

```
[development_company_database].[dbo].
```

Comment: Why would you not want to hard-code the database names? I can see how you would want to avoid sprinkling the database name through the code, but using dynamic SQL to work around this is going to lead to messier (And probably slower) code. If you ever would need to replace the database name, do a simple search and replace instead.

Comment: @SchmitzIT : can I assign connection details to @variables and use them? something like `@serverMan.fx_Rights_ORGIDs`

Comment: Yes, you could do that. However, you'd have to store the query in a SQL character stirng. I.e. `SELECT @sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @database + '.' + @owner + '.tableName'`. It's going to complicate the debugging process though in case something goes wrong. I usually end up `PRINT @sql` to generate an executable statement that can then be copy/pasted into a new window for testing the result set.

Comment: I'd still try and avoiding it if I were you, for the reasons I mentioned above. Readability is reduced, complexity is increased, and I'm pretty certain there'll be a performance hit you'll take for using dynamically generated SQL.

Answer (score 0):

For an alternative view on things, I'd say there are a couple of factors I would consider here.

1. Is the database name and location consistent? If so and you're the only person running it, hardcoding a portable script isn't so bad. However, personally, if the database name changes, I'd rather just change one entry at the top of the script and be sure that it's consistent throughout. 
   An alternative would be to use the Template functionality in SSMS 2012. This in essence does the same thing as Ctrl+H.
   I suppose it depends on how much you plan to change this script in the future.
2. Is this a stored procedure? If you're running it a lot then it probably should be, and if so, hardcoded database names aren't ideal. Better to declare variables and set them at run time.

I run a lot of scripts with dynamic SQL without a performance hit. The only way to be sure is to compare the performance of the two and reach your own conclusions there.